# Vertically align a div next to another div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Please review this [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/4NA89/embedded/result/).

You'll notice I have two colums, side by side, and content under the headers. I'm trying to align the Lorem Ipsum with the vertical center of the paragraph to the right.

I thought a vertical align set to the column 1 would would, but it's not.

```
.col1-row1 {
    margin-top: 2%; 
    display: inline-block; 
    background: transparent; 
    padding: 5px; 
    width:45%; 
    margin-left: 4%; 
    color: #f8981d; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    line-height: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "col1-row1" and "col2-row1" to display: table-cell instead of inline-block, and then include vertical-align: middle.

Answer (score 0):

just replace this css for col1-row1 and col2-row1 classes in your stylesheet,this works fine in your fiddle.

```
.col1-row1 {
          margin-top: 2%; 
        display: inline-block; 
        background: transparent; 
        padding: 5px; 
        width:45%; 
        color: #f8981d; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-size: 20px; 
        line-height: 20px; 
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align: center;
    }

.col2-row1 {
    margin-top: 2%; 
    display: inline-block; 
    background: transparent; 
    padding: 5px; 
    width: 45%; 
    color: #f8981d; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    line-height: 20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can pre-determine the height of the right-hand block of text, you can do something like the following (I set it at 206px):

```
<style>
#container {
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div.left {
    width:460px;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
div.right {
    width:460px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
div.clear {
    clear: both;
}
div.left p {
    height:206px;
    line-height: 206px;
}
div.right p {
    height:206px;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div class="left">
        <h1>Exemption Reason</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <h1>Documentation Required</h1>
        <p>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at nunc convallis, venenatis lectus auctor, porta nisi. Donec sit amet mauris non justo ultrices dignissim sed at ipsum. Aliquam accumsan faucibus nunc, id pulvinar massa consequat at. Pellentesque sed mauris leo. Nullam pulvinar sit amet tortor a suscipit. Ut varius et eros a aliquam. Donec tortor nisi, tristique at feugiat at, malesuada eu tortor. Pellentesque quis sapien mauris. Mauris pulvinar posuere auctor. Praesent nec felis at mi ultricies elementum. Nulla vitae pharetra mi, et semper ipsum. Etiam eget tristique mi. Vivamus rutrum ipsum dapibus enim malesuada sodales. Nullam rhoncus elit ut condimentum tincidunt. Quisque dapibus lorem eget euismod mattis. Praesent id consectetur urna.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

If the height of the paragraph in the right hand column is dynamic and can not be determined beforehand, you can use JavaScript (here I'm using jQuery):

```
<style>
#container {
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div.left {
    width:460px;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
div.right {
    width:460px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
div.clear {
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div class="left">
        <h1>Exemption Reason</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <h1>Documentation Required</h1>
        <p>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at nunc convallis, venenatis lectus auctor, porta nisi. Donec sit amet mauris non justo ultrices dignissim sed at ipsum. Aliquam accumsan faucibus nunc, id pulvinar massa consequat at. Pellentesque sed mauris leo. Nullam pulvinar sit amet tortor a suscipit. Ut varius et eros a aliquam. Donec tortor nisi, tristique at feugiat at, malesuada eu tortor. Pellentesque quis sapien mauris. Mauris pulvinar posuere auctor. Praesent nec felis at mi ultricies elementum. Nulla vitae pharetra mi, et semper ipsum. Etiam eget tristique mi. Vivamus rutrum ipsum dapibus enim malesuada sodales. Nullam rhoncus elit ut condimentum tincidunt. Quisque dapibus lorem eget euismod mattis. Praesent id consectetur urna.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var target_height = $('div.right p').height()+'px';
    $('div.left p').css({
        'height': target_height,
        'lineHeight': target_height
    });
});
</script>
```